# Router drops internet connection if I connect an additional PC

Tags: networking, router, connection

I'm using a SMC2804WBRP-G router connected to my ADSL-modem. Usually there are two computers connected to this router: a win7 ultimate desktop(wired) and a macbook air (wireless). Both working absolutely fine and never caused any connection drops as far as I know.

A new room mate moved in last month and each time she starts up her win7 home laptop the router looses the internet connection. The laptop is on a wired connection.

The first time she connected to my router, the connection dropped every 2 mins. To find out whats wrong with her machine I disabled all unnecessary services etc. besides the anti virus software. That helped to eliminate almost all of those periodic connection drops. But the start up drop remained and I've got the feeling that the router is still loosing connection from time to time.

I haven't had the time to find out what service caused the periodic drops. But I'm more concerned about is that start up drop.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to look for the problem? I would be very thankful for any hints or tips!

Comment: Sounds like the computer has a fixed IP address. Change it to DHCP and see if that helps.

Comment: I'll double check that. But I'm pretty sure its not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The new laptop may be infected with a botnet virus.  The traffic may be detected by the ISP and the modem disabled.  When the connection goes down, is the ADSL modem still connecting to the Internet?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to scan all the machines on the network now, simply because a virus is a possibility. If this does happen, make sure they're not plugged in to each other, to prevent any possible spread of infection.

Comment: I think not. Its reconnecting pretty fast. But for the time the drop happens I'm not able to access my router's controls. I've been monitoring my connection via wireshark when those periodic drops occurred and I think I've seen some sort of RST (reset) command being send by either the router or the laptop. But I didn't bother to look into that because disabling her services helped a lot and hadn't had the time back then.

Comment: RST is just a standard part of the IP stack.  What do the status lights on the modem and the router do when there's an outage?

Comment: Mmh, I'm gonna have to check that tomorrow morning. She's already asleep right now ;-)

Comment: So I've just experienced another drop and the router completely lost connection. I had to reset the router by pulling the plug, because I couldn't even get a connection to it directly.

Comment: But what was the status of the lights on the router and the modem?  We can't pin it down unless we can determine which device is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple fix. If you listen to these tech guys they'll have you running around in circles:

1. Click on start,
2. Click on control panel,
3. Double click on network connections,
4. Right click on the internet connection you are using,
5. Click on properties,
6. In window click on Internet Protocol (TCP/IP) to highlight it,
7. Click on properties,
8. At bottom click on  use following DNS server,
9. At Preferred DNS server enter 208.67.222.222,
10. At Alternate DNS server enter 208.67.220.220,
11. click OK, close everything out.

If you follow these directions it should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my router would lose connection everytime my sons pc woke from sleep. After trying all kinds of stuff, i found i had a network switch connected to another network switch, which had one of it cables going back to the source switch by accident. Of course once i removed that 2nd cable it was fine.

Just wanted to post somewhere to maybe help another poor SOB one day struggling with this issue. Check your cable routing.

Comment: That's a loop and it causes a packet storm. Glad you figured it out but it's not related to the question that was asked here.